# Приложение оффлайн справочник

Tags: android

**Суть приложения:**

Справочник, где есть категории и подкатегории.
В справочнике будет текстовая информация и немного картинок.

**Вопрос:**

Как лучше всего организовать оффлайн хранение текстовой инфы ?
Хранить в каком-то формате(csv, например) в папке raw или где ?
Нужно, чтобы юзер скачав приложение - уже имел инфу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Андроид имеет все необходимое для работы с полноценной локальной БД SQLite, ее и надо использовать в вашем случае. Как подключить в свой проект уже заполненную БД SQLite уже обсуждалось на этом ресурсе. БД позволит легко и грамотно реализовать такие необходимые функции справочника, как поиск, фильтрация, теги и тп. так как сделана специально для обработки информации и работает очень быстро, в отличии от текстовых файлов, CSV, JSON и тп. структур.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик! Склонялся к SQLite, но мне не понятен вопрос как наполнять эту самую базу без танцев с бубном ?

Comment: @researcher Для PC (настольных компьютеров) есть множество программ - менеджеров баз данных SQLite, с помощью которых можно достаточно комфортно заполнить базу, а так же оттестировать и администрировать ее. Из бесплатных я отдаю свое предпочтение программе [SQLite Expert Personal](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/download.html) - free-версия имеет очень хороший набор функций, достаточный для полноценной работы, тестирования и обслуживания БД. Затем, уже подготовленную на PC базу использовать в android-приложении.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать!

Answer (score 2):

Для таких целей отлично подойдет [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/), многие приложения используют ее.